# The server principal **** is not able to access **** the database under the current security context

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange error in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I mapped to be db_owner in `myDB`.

But when I log into SQL Server and try to expand the database tab I got this error:

> The server principal "myLocalUser" is not able to access  the database "anotherDB" under the current security context

The error refers to **another db**...

I don't know why it try to connect the "another db".

The error be fixed when I get permission to "another db" although I don't use it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are there any SYNONYMS in `myDB` that point to objects in `anotherDB`?

Comment: I don't think....I know the db well and don't need the anotherDB...
How can I check it?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/desiree/the-server-principal-a-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-b-under-the-current-security-context-microsoft-sql-server-error-916/

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a profiler, put a filter on it for "another db" and "myLocalUser" and you're sure to see what the offending statement is.

Comment: But it occurred before I start the application...The application thar reference to myDB work well without permission to AnotherDB..

Comment: My statement stands. Fire up the profiler and see what's going on.